# How to keep polyline and svg shape object connection when svg shape object moves

Tags: d3.js, svg

I want to connect two svg shape objects using polyline.I draw two svg shape objects one by one and after that I draw that polyline to connect those shape objects.If i move one svg shape object that polyline should be come with that shape object.Polyline and svg object connection should fixed after drawing polyline.

I draw shapes like this

```
    var sampleSVG = svg;
          sampleSVG.append('circle')
          .attr('id', 'startcricle'+idstartelement++)
          .style("stroke", "black")
          .style("stroke-width", "1.5")
          .style("fill", "white")
          .attr('transform', 'translate(' + '100' + ',' + '100' + ')')
          .attr('r', '20')
          .on("mouseover",function(d){
           var t = d3.select(this).attr("id");

       function getScreenCoords(x, y, ctm) {
        var xn = ctm.e + x*ctm.a + y*ctm.c;
        var yn = ctm.f + x*ctm.b + y*ctm.d;
        return { x: xn, y: yn };
      }

      var circle = document.getElementById(t),
      cx = +circle.getAttribute('cx'),
      cy = +circle.getAttribute('cy'),
      ctm = circle.getCTM(),
      coords = getScreenCoords(cx, cy, ctm);
      if(arrowbuttonclick==1){
        startx=coords.x;
        starty=coords.y;
        arrowbuttonclick=2;
      }else if (arrowbuttonclick==2) {
        endx=coords.x;
        endy=coords.y;

        arrowpath(startx,starty,endx,endy);

        midx = startx+((endx-startx)/2);
        console.log("ok2")
        console.log(startx+","+starty+","+midx+","+starty+","+midx+","+endy+","+endx+","+endy)

  sampleSVG.append("polyline")      // attach a polyline
    .style("stroke", "black")  // colour the line
    .style("fill", "none")     // remove any fill colour
    .attr("points", startx+","+starty+","+midx+","+starty+","+midx+","+endy+","+endx+","+endy); 

    startx=0;
    starty=0;
    endx=0;
    endy=0;
    arrowbuttonclick=0;
  }
})
          .call(drag)

        });
```

When I click line button I change arrowbuttonclick=1.After select svg shapes it take coordinates and draw polyline.

Do i need to remove current two svg objects and create new svg objects with polyline to do this task or is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: You have to recalculate the x's and y's inside the drag functions callback.
A not perfect example: https://jsfiddle.net/he0f4u23/2/. The drag behaviour works for the 2 rectangle except the bottom left one.

Comment: I want polyline because i can draw only vertical and horizontal lines.